# Why are the values returned by getWidth() and getHeight() double the actual image dimensions?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-studio

I'm developing for Android, and my program involves a lot of bitmap images - these are set using BitmapFactory. One of my images is 80x30, and I assign it to a Bitmap variable wit the following instruction:

```
bmapImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(currContext.getResources(), R.drawable.brick);
```

When I then use the instruction

```
myImgWidth = bmapImg.getWidth();
```

myImgWidth is evaluated to 160 instead of 80. Likewise, when I run

```
myImgHeight = bmapImg.getHeight();
```

myImgHeight is evaluated to 60 instead of 30. I've looked through other questions on StackOverflow relating to these methods, but all of those issues were about getWidth() and getHeight() returning 0. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a reason as to why these functions return double the actual image dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You using `decodeResource`, so image is scaled based on your DPI. To scale it to size you need, place it in different folder. I suggest drawable_xhdpi is what you need, if scale factor is 2.

And keep in mind, it will be scaled on devices with different screen density.

To completely avoid scaling you may put your image to assets folder for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about which screen you are running your app on. The values returned by those methods are the pixels that the image takes on the current screen. They will return values that are 1:1 with your image's resolution if you are running on a mdpi screen and you used 80dp and 30dp respectively for their dimensions.  I would bet you are probably running your app on a  xhdpi screen and do not have a resource for that density bucket

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answer, image is resized based on the device you check on.

If you don't want android to resize your image based on DPI, I recommend you to add your image in  *drawable-nodpi* folder of your project